# AWS wordcount issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, emr, bigdata

I'm beginner in AWS, I tried to run wordcount (I tried the jar on local it work perfectly) but on EMR using amazon web service, I used this tutorial ( [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyRxq8YwZcU&t=291](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyRxq8YwZcU&t=291s)s ) and I specified argument:

```
<-inputfile s3://xxx/data/aa.txt -outputdir s3://xxxx/res >
```

But always failed to launch, and I want to know to run a custom jar on AWS, should I integrate AWS API or not?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The Short Question is, when i want to run custom Jar in AWS should i integrate AWS API before to build the jar or not?

Comment: You mean AWS SDK as dependency while building your JAR ?

Comment: I mean should i integrate AWS librabrie in my java code before to build the jar or not?